# "MFC/C++ Socket programming.." How to connect server and client?

Tags: c++, networking, mfc

I used a code for MFC/C++  socket programming but it's only working when I make the server and client on the same PC , but when I use the client  on different PC ,it fails to find the server and the connection is failed . 
I don't know if the problem with the local  IP  of the server I use or with the code any help please :) !

the following code is server side :-

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <afxext.h>
#include <afxsock.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0);
    AfxSocketInit();
    CSocket serverSocket;
    serverSocket.Create(3333);
    serverSocket.Listen();
    CSocket clientSocket;

    while(serverSocket.Accept(clientSocket))
    {
        CString s;

        while(s!="bye")
        {
            char msg[128];

            if(clientSocket.Receive(msg, 128)<0)break;

            s = msg;
            cout<<"Client: "<<msg<<endl;
            sprintf_s(msg, 128, "Your msg (%d letter) arrived successfully.",
            strlen(msg));
            clientSocket.Send(msg, 128);

            if(s=="shutdown")exit(0);
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the following code for client side :-

```
 #include <afx.h>
 #include <afxext.h>
 #include <afxsock.h>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0);
    AfxSocketInit();
    CSocket clientSocket;
    clientSocket.Create();

    if(clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.2", 3333))
    {
        cout<<"Connected to server."<<endl;
        CString s;

        while(s!="bye" && s!="shutdown")
        {
            char msg[128];
            cin.getline(msg, 128);
            s = msg;
            clientSocket.Send(msg, 128);

            if(clientSocket.Receive(msg, 128)<0)break;

            cout<<msg<<endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       cout<<"Cannot find server."<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `ping`-ing the server PC from the client PC first.

Answer (score 1):

How about attempting to connect to another server address in your client **instead** of your currently fixed address?

```
if(clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.2", 3333))
```

P.S. It is always best to set parameters in your programs for such things as addresses and port numbers..

Comment: when i used this ip "41.47.9.91" , it dos't connect , is there problem  with this IP ??

Comment: "41.47.9.91" is a public internet address. Does your client computer have access to internet? Are there any firewalls between the client computer and internet and between "41.47.9.91" computer and internet?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the server socket first

```
serverSocket.Bind(3333)
```

and then listen.